# Extract multiple Cognos report definitions

Tags: cognos

In COGNOS is there a way to get the definitions (filters, selected fields) from a number of reports in a folder?

I've inherited around 500 reports defined in a folder and they all need to be checked and fixed as they have business errors (not technical errors).  If it was possible to get all their definitions in a single extract that would save an enormous amount of time having to click multiple times to get that information from each report one by one.

In ACCESS this can be done with VBA (for query definitions), but I'm not sure if there is a scripting language that can be used with COGNOS to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to "validate" each of these 500 reports (effectively equivalent to pressing the "validate" button on each individual report if it was open in the authoring studio).

Validation will ensure that a report specification XML is still syntactically correct, references a package which is still present the content store, references only query items from that package which still exist, generates valid SQL vs. the underlying datasource, etc.

If that's what you're looking for, an easy way to do batch validation for all 500 reports would be to use MotioPI (its a free admin tool for Cognos).  Here's a short article which walks you through the process:

http://info.motio.com/Blog/bid/70357/Batch-Validation-of-Cognos-Reports

If you're wanting to retrieve the actual report specification (XML) for each of these 500 objects, then you'd need to write a program which utilizes the Cognos SDK to retrieve the specification XML from each of the 500 report objects. After that, you'd need to add logic which examines each of these 500 XML documents, looking for whatever it is you're looking for.

Comment: I'm wanting to retrieve the XML, change and create new XML and save it.  The SDK option is not available to me - is there a way to do it via VBA through an API?  I found this but am struggling to see how it might be used to change report specifications: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHM9K_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cxr.10.2.2.doc/c_coc_sdk_cocapifunctions.html#coc_sdk_COCAPIFunctions

Comment: Can you integrate / utilize VB or VB.NET from VBA?  If so, the SDK is the route I would suggest. 

BTW - a while back IBM changed the licensing model so that the SDK is effectively free (eg http://ykud.com/blog/cognos/bi/finally-cognos-bi-software-development-kit-is-free-to-use). 

The SDK includes a set of client side libraries that make it easy for you to invoke web services exposed by the Cognos BI server.  The installation includes examples written in Java, C# and VB. 

A classic SDK example is retrieving a set of report specs, updating them, then saving them back to Cognos.

Comment: Please provide link to the classic SDK example - this is exactly what I'm after.  I've tried the link and the follow up google query with no luck.

Comment: Here's a link to a the 10.2.2 SDK documentation on the web, around that topic (this is high level, not the actual source code): http://ibm.co/2iHOh8i

To get all the actual source code for the examples, you have to install the SDK (the samples come with it). The SDK installation is available from IBM download site (get your Cognos admin to grab it), get the version that matches your Cognos version & install it on the Cognos server (after that, you can copy the client libs & examples to your client machine for easier reference).

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by exporting the XML of the reports using a SQL query on the content store.
The output is processed with a Python script to convert XML to table layout in CSV format. 
This CSV-file can easely be imported in Excel.

You might want to process the reports XML directly in a SQL query with the xmltable function. In our situation this turned out to be a heavy proces we don't want to burden the content store database with. For a small set of reports this is working fine though.